# Proof of Cauchy's functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, functional-equations

I came across Cauchy's functional equation recently and am trying to understand the proofs for it - there are many, but almost all of which are very difficult for me to understand. I know that solutions to the equation $$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$$ are of the form $$f(q) = cq\ \forall\ c \in \mathbb{Q}.$$

Wikipedia provides a very nice proof of it using just elementary algebra [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Solutions_over_the_rational_numbers).

I understand all of the proof except for one line, which has got to do with the case where $q > 0$ is considered. I will re-write (part of) the proof below for convenience.

If $q > 0$, then $f(qx) = qf(x)\ \forall\ q \in \mathbb{Q}^+$.

$\implies f(q) = qf(1)$

I know the proof goes from $f(qx) = qf(x)$ to $f(q) = qf(1)$ by letting $x = 1$, but why is this sufficient for a proof? I mean, if I let $x$ take another value, then $c$ would be a different constant right? Doesn't the proof have to be general, in the sense that it covers all values of $x$?

This seems like a trivial observation and maybe it is - it has been a long day of me staring at numbers, but anyone kind enough to explain how it can be concluded that $f(q) = qf(1)$ will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you are a bit confused. It should be more like $f(q) = cq\ \forall\, q,$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}.$ For any such function $\,f\,$ the $\,c\,$ is fixed, but $f(q) = cq$ holds for all $q\in\mathbb{R}$ as well but in particular for rational $q$.

Comment: @Somos Oh, I see what you are trying to say. Yes, yours should be more accurate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set $x= 1$ in your relation $f(qx) = q\,f(x)$.

Edit: To show some function is linear (over $\mathbb{R}_+$, for example), it suffices to show $f(x) = c\,x$, and of course, $c = f(1)$.

Comment: Yes, I suppose, but then why not, say, $x = 2$? Because the proof goes on to mention right at the end that $c = f(1)$. If I chose another value for $x$, then $c$ would be another constant right?

Comment: I mean, this is a different question, I only provide the answer for the question given in your problem statement. If you want me to say more, it is your obligation to state more in your problem statement

Comment: But the relation holds for all x, so surely must hold for when x=1.

Comment: @FeiCao Right. Sorry, I edited my question. Maybe you can re-write your answer :) I will still mark your answer as accepted when I can though.

Comment: @EthanMark You would not get a different value for $c$. If you plugged in $x = 2$, the equation would become $f(2q) = qf(2)$. Note that the $q$ inside the $f$ doesn't match the $q$ multiplying $f(2)$, but if we substitute $r = 2q$ we find that
$$
f(r) = r \cdot \left(\frac 12 f(2)\right),
$$
which is consistent with the result $f(r) = r \cdot f(1)$ since $f(2) = 2f(1)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I see. I kind of get it already, but you mentioned that "the $q$ inside the $f$ doesn't match the $q$ multiplying $f(2)$". If that is the case, how can we substitute the same $r$ for both $q$'s? Also, wouldn't it be clearer to say, $f(2a) = bf(2)$ then? Or am I just confusing myself further...

Comment: @EthanMark You are welcome! But I think Ben Grossmann's comment is enough to answer your question

Comment: @EthanMark I don't mean each $q$ refers to a different number. What I mean is that we are looking for an expression of the form $f(q) = \_ \cdot q$, but we have a $2q$ in the parentheses instead of a $q$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I edited my answer as well, thank you!

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh... That's right. I see now. Thank you for the help :)